# How to adjust timestamp to yesterday date on MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can anybody please tell me how to add a yesterday time stamp whenever my table get updated? Currently, it giving me today date instead yesterday date. Please see below picture.

I tired adding `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -1)` on default/Expression. Did not work.

[image]

Comment Picture

[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` to subtract one day from today's date. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(Date) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

**UPDATE**

To update the value in the database, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE column = 'value'
```

Comment: I don't think it going to work for me, because I manually fixed the dates on already inserted data. I can not manually do this every day. So I am looking for a way to change it whenever I am inserting data. Hopefully, this will make sense.  Please see the Comment Picture. Today it got updated with yesterday data. So today date should change to yesterday.  Thank you so much

Comment: @Suneth You mean when you update a row in the database, you want to set the date to yesterday's date?

Comment: Yes, I have it to current date. I want to change it to yesterday date

Comment: @Suneth I updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I need this to be automate. I am already doing it manually. I just want to automate it whenever API run in the morning. So I don't have to do it manually every time process runs.

`UPDATE simplymacstaging.locationtest SET create_time = '2019-04-15' WHERE CONVERT(create_time, date) = '2019-04-16'` 
Does it make sense, what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: @Suneth Can't you modify the API to do so?

Comment: There i no date coming from API. I am creating date on Database.

Comment: @Suneth I don't understand. Isn't the API doing the updating in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed the same, to update yesterday date whenever my table gets data. I have scheduled the following query, which worked perfectly for me.

I hope it will work for you also:

```
sql_yesterday_date = 'UPDATE tbl_dailytrade SET Date = subdate(current_date, 1) WHERE Date(date) = CURDATE()'
```